# how can set a value to select control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a select control.  I want to bind an item that was selected before to it. I want to bind an item in edit view. The below code does not work.

```
<select id="sel">
    @foreach( var item in ....)
    {         
        <option value="@item.id" >
           Item.name
        </option>
    }
</select>
```

In script:

```
       $('#sel').val ("@(...getidproduct (item.prop))")
```

Getidproduct returns the correct value, but it does not bind to select.

Comment: $(**'#sel'**).val(...)

Comment: Notice the # in his comment

Answer (score 0):

You need to add #

> $('#sel').val()

Comment: No no I mistake here . I wrote it true in my project .

Comment: It is not because of this